# ios/android camera capture then send image to dynamically changing webpage

Tags: android, iphone, camera, html, device

I'm the drummer in a band here in Denver and we CONSTANTLY have fans taking pix of us, taking selfies with us behind them on stage. Or the aftershow selfies.

What I'm trying to work out is the following:

1. A page on our website that will essentially host a "take or upload photo" button.
2. After the person submits the photo, it will be immediately displayed on the same webpage (newest to oldest preferrably)
3. Of course there will always be that jackass who takes a picture of something stupid or offensive and submits it so, we need the ability for our manager to (simply & immediately) delete said photo from the stream. We need her to sort of "monitor" the shots as they come in.

Ok.. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is two version of your app. One is displayed and managed my your manager or team and other by all your fans depends on the who is signing in. Once fan take the pic they will upload through there application. It will host to the server by whatever web services you are using. Your team will get the notification immediately that so and so pics or comments get uploaded. Once your team approves it will dynamically uploaded to your website. If your team rejects it, user may/may not get notification for rejection.